# Event when a multicast address is added to the tap driver

Tags: c, network-programming, linux-device-driver, multicast

I'm in the process of porting a user-space network driver to a newer linux version.

The idea is to get rid of a custom kernel module that connected the network stack of the kernel to the driver and use TUN/TAP instead.

The problem I face now is with adding/removing multicast addresses that the driver should listen to on the wire.

I know how to obtain the list of current multicast addresses for the interface with

```
cat /proc/net/dev_mcast
```

But I don't get any event when the list changes.

When the driver should listen to a new multicast address, user space calls:

```
struct ip_mreq group;
group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("226.1.1.1");     // multicast address
group.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("172.16.72.100"); // interface address

setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *) &group, sizeof(group));
```

This leads in the kernel to a call of

```
struct net_device_op.ndo_set_rx_mode
```

The driver then can update its (hardware) multicast filters.

Unfortunately the callback in the TAP driver is empty.

Is there any alternative way to detect changes in the multicast reception (without polling)?

I tried netlink messages, but the RTNLGRP_NEIGH doesn't report changes to the multicast addresses.

Monitoring /proc/net/dev_mcast with inotify also doesn't work, as inotify is not supported on virtual file systems.

Thanks,
   Wolfgang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usespace routing daemons normally listen to a [routing netlink socket](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/7-rtnetlink/) and [epoll](http://bitsup.blogspot.com/2008/04/monitoring-ip-changes-with-netlink.html) for status to react to events. I think that should give you the desired behavior.

If you have to do more advanced multicast routing you may want to look into a special Linux kernel hook meant for multicast routing daemons to manage the multicast route table labeled CONFIG_IP_MROUTE.

The mechanism is explained well in this article:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6070

An example of a simple multicast routing daemon that uses this hook is:
http://troglobit.com/projects/smcroute/

Comment: I already opened a netlink socket and subscribed to all available groups. I tried "ip monitor" which does the same according to strace. All this provided no event in case of IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP. And using the interface provided for mcast routing daemons is too complex for my application. As I'm on an embedded system I ended up patching the kernel/TUN module. Thanks for your help.